# Адаптивная высота для вертикального расположения блоков slick slider

Tags: html, jquery, css

Пыталась решить задачу и наткнулась на такую проблему.

Есть [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) с вертикальным расположением блоков (`vertical: true`). 
В каждом блоке "спрятано" изображение к тексту. При выборе активного (либо центрального) слайда появляется это скрытое изображение.

Но слайдер почему-то "неадекватно" себя ведет (то скачет, то все слайды отображает вместо положенных 3-х). `adaptiveHeight` - не работает для вертикального расположения блоков.

**Вопрос:** Как решить данную проблему, чтобы вертикальных слайдов было 3 (к примеру), центральный (или просто активный) был с изображением? Как решить проблему с адаптивной высотой блоков для вертикального расположения блоков в slick slider?

Код:

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  infinite: false,
  centerMode: true,
  vertical: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  asNavFor: '.control',
});

$('.control').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,  
  asNavFor: '.slider',
  focusOnSelect: true,
  vertical: true
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body,
  html {
    position: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  body,
  html,
  .wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  p {
    font-size: .75rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    color: #333;
  }

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .wrap {
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }

  .slider {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }

  .control {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    padding: .5rem;
  }

  .slider.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
  }

  .slider.slick-vertical .slick-slide img {
    display: none;
  }


  .slider.slick-vertical .slick-current img,
  .slider.slick-vertical .slick-center img {
    display: block;
  }

  .slider.slick-vertical .slick-current p,
  .slider.slick-vertical .slick-center p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  .control.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: .5rem;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="slider">
    <div>
        <p>
          1/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos atque saepe beatae esse necessitatibus maxime tempora eos quisquam et voluptas?
        </p>

        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/ccc/fff&text=img-1" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
          2/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos atque saepe beatae esse necessitatibus maxime tempora eos quisquam et voluptas?
        </p>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/ccc/fff&text=img-2" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
          3/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos atque saepe beatae esse necessitatibus maxime tempora eos quisquam et voluptas?
        </p>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/ccc/fff&text=img-3" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
          4/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos atque saepe beatae esse necessitatibus maxime tempora eos quisquam et voluptas?
        </p>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/ccc/fff&text=img-4" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
          5/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos atque saepe beatae esse necessitatibus maxime tempora eos quisquam et voluptas?
        </p>
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/ccc/fff&text=img-5" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control">
    <div>
        <p>
          1/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ipsa atque possimus numquam cumque dolores eaque, voluptatibus ex eos. Nisi aspernatur quia deserunt libero doloremque blanditiis animi? Optio officiis dignissimos perferendis aperiam tenetur reprehenderit, odio dolores asperiores perspiciatis nobis doloribus soluta explicabo ut neque repellat quia molestiae consequuntur maxime quis!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
          2/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ipsa atque possimus numquam cumque dolores eaque, voluptatibus ex eos. Nisi aspernatur quia deserunt libero doloremque blanditiis animi? Optio officiis dignissimos perferendis aperiam tenetur reprehenderit, odio dolores asperiores perspiciatis nobis doloribus soluta explicabo ut neque repellat quia molestiae consequuntur maxime quis!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
          3/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ipsa atque possimus numquam cumque dolores eaque, voluptatibus ex eos. Nisi aspernatur quia deserunt libero doloremque blanditiis animi? Optio officiis dignissimos perferendis aperiam tenetur reprehenderit, odio dolores asperiores perspiciatis nobis doloribus soluta explicabo ut neque repellat quia molestiae consequuntur maxime quis!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
          4/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ipsa atque possimus numquam cumque dolores eaque, voluptatibus ex eos. Nisi aspernatur quia deserunt libero doloremque blanditiis animi? Optio officiis dignissimos perferendis aperiam tenetur reprehenderit, odio dolores asperiores perspiciatis nobis doloribus soluta explicabo ut neque repellat quia molestiae consequuntur maxime quis!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
          5/ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ipsa atque possimus numquam cumque dolores eaque, voluptatibus ex eos. Nisi aspernatur quia deserunt libero doloremque blanditiis animi? Optio officiis dignissimos perferendis aperiam tenetur reprehenderit, odio dolores asperiores perspiciatis nobis doloribus soluta explicabo ut neque repellat quia molestiae consequuntur maxime quis!
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```